# How to calculate php for loop values using javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have   it's show some values in forloop.i want to calculate those values and add it to textbox.this is my code

```
<?php
 $itemCount = count($_POST["opt"]);
 for($i=0;$i<$itemCount;$i++) {
        $op_name=$_POST['opt'][$i];
        $price=$_POST['price'][$i];
?>
 <tr>
     <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $op_name;?>" name="opt" /></td>
     <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $price;?>" name="price" id="price" style="width: 40px;" onkeyup="order()"/></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="amt" style="width: 40px;" id="amount" onkeyup="order()" /></td>
 </tr>

 <?php
    }
 ?>
Total <input type="text" value="<?php echo $tot;?>" id="tot" />onkeyup="order()"/>
```

javascript

```
function order(){
    var price=document.getElementById("price").value;
    var amt=document.getElementById("amount").value;
    var cal_price=1*price;
    var cal_amt=1*amt;
    document.getElementById("tot").value =((cal_price)*(cal_amt));
    }
```

my code calculate only first row values.i want all Price*ammount total to display in textbox

[image]

Comment: Use document.getElementByName instead of getElementById because your inputs have no ids attributes

Comment: I would recommend to add CSS class names to price and amount fields, because IDs should never be duplicate inside a page's DOM. If you don't want to use a library like JQuery, you should then use `getElementsByClassName()` and modify your code to iterate over all elements returned. Here's [a sample](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_document_getelementsbyclassname_loop) how this can be used.

Comment: @Fourat - there is no singular version of getElementsByName

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. ID needs to be unique.
2. PHP will handle your fields as arrays if you name the fields with `[]` for example `name="price[]"`.
3. use `document.getElementsByName("price[]")`to get a collection of price fields

Like this

```js
function order() {
  var prices = document.getElementsByName("price[]");
  var amts = document.getElementsByName("amt[]");
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < prices.length; i++) {
    var cal_price = 1 * prices[i].value; // or parseFloat(prices[i].value)
    var cal_amt = 1 * amts[i].value; // or parseInt(amts[i].value,10)
    total += cal_price * cal_amt;
  }
  document.getElementById("tot").value = total.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="" name="opt[]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="1.5" name="price[]" style="width: 40px;" onkeyup="order()" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="amt[]" style="width: 40px;" onkeyup="order()" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="" name="opt[]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="2.5" name="price[]" style="width: 40px;" onkeyup="order()" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="amt[]" style="width: 40px;" onkeyup="order()" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="" name="opt[]" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="3.25" name="price[]" style="width: 40px;" onkeyup="order()" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="amt[]" style="width: 40px;" onkeyup="order()" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="text" id="tot" />
```

Comment: Would not `parseFloat(prices[i])` be a better solution than `1*prices[i]`

Comment: Actually (+prices[i]) would work too. I did not change the 1* since it works and I did not want to change too much of the original code

Comment: Was about to write the same in a fiddle as example. Your code has some errors. Please look at https://jsfiddle.net/agg801py/5/ for a working implementation of this solution